# Powershell "Get-MailboxImportRequest | Remove-MailboxImportRequestStatistics" list

Tags: powershell

I have migrated a number of mailboxes from an OnPrem Exchange to Office365 prior to migrating live users mailboxes.

Each time the commands have been run (in this case `New-MoveRequest`) the command `Get-MailboxImportRequest | Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics` has been run in order to monitor the progress of the task.

Each time this is run now it appears previous tasks run show in the list including failed tasks making reading the current task onerous, so I am looking to simplify the view.

I have tried `Clear-History` and `Clear-History -ID` but neither have removed/ cleared the list.

If anyone could advise what command I could run to clear the task command list I would be grateful.

Get_MailboxImportrequest
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [`Remove-MailboxImportRequest` MS Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/remove-mailboximportrequest?view=exchange-ps) it appears that completed Mailbox Import Requests are not cleared.

The example given on that page appears to be what you are looking for:

```
Get-MailboxImportRequest -Status Completed | Remove-MailboxImportRequest
```

Comment: The command to view jobs, active, completed and failed is 

Get-MailboxImportRequest | Get-MailboxImportRequestStatistics

The command to clear completed (successful) jobs is 

Get-MailboxImportRequest -Status Completed | Remove-MailboxImportRequest

The command to clear incomplete (failed) jobs is

Get-MailboxImportRequest -Status Failed | Remove-MailboxImportRequest

 

I appreciate the feedback :)